# How external linkage of member functions occurs?

Tags: c++, linkage

I have two Translation Units with the following codes:

```
//Translation Unit A
struct A {
    void f(int a) {};
};
//Translation Unit B
void f(int j);
int main()
{
    f(4);
}
```

In the `translation unit A` , `struct A` belongs to global scope so it have external linkage,so the member function name `f` also have external linkage. In the second `translation unit` the function `f` declared also have external linkage. The definition of external linkage according to C++ draft ISO N°4901(2021):

> When a name has external linkage, the entity it denotes can be
> referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from
> other scopes of the same translation unit.

When I run the code although I get a Link error. Why this happens? How is the linkage suppose to occur?

Comment: Where did you put the definition of `void f(int j);`? That's not the same as `A::f()`.

Comment: `void f(int j);` and `struct A { void f(int a) {};};` are two completely unrelated functions

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the definition, in my understanding could be the definition of the member function.

Comment: @UnholySheep.  doesn't the two have the same name? http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-9

Comment: No, not at all - the C++ compiler mangles those at compile time. Otherwise you'd never be allowed to have any member functions with the same name as member functions of other classes.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The member function already has a definition, but if it didn't, one would have to define it outside of its class like this: `void A::f() {}`, which is different from `void f(){}`. These are different functions despite having the same name. The name alone is not enough to identify a function.

Comment: I agree, but the functions have the same identifier right? If they are the same they are the same name.@UnholySheep

Comment: "If they are the same they are the same name". But the opposite is not true. If they have the same name, they are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, they aren't the same. But the linkage shouldn't tie them? If in the `translation unit A` we put the function definition in the global scope the linker wouldn't comply. We would have the same situation: same name, external linkage, function definition in `TU A` and declaration in `TU B`. But the result is different

Comment: No, the linkage ties names that refer to the same entity, and these functions are different entities.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions

- `A::foo` which is declared in TU A and has also `inline` definition there.
- `::foo` in TU B which has only been declared, not defined.

`foo` symbol in `main` resolves to the latter, since the linker was not able to find its definition, it emits an error.